# String index out of range: 1 JAVA

Tags: java

I am testing to see if the string the user entered in is a valid phone number but get

> "String index out of range: 1"

whenever I try to run the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String number = "";
    boolean d1 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(1));
    boolean d2 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(2));
    boolean d3 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(3));

    boolean d5 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(5));
    boolean d6 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(6));
    boolean d7 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(7));

    boolean d9 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(9));
    boolean d10 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(10));
    boolean d11 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(11));
    boolean d12 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(12));

    System.out.println("Please enter a phone number (ddd)ddd-dddd :");
    number = sc.nextLine();

    if ((number.length() == 13) && (number.charAt(0)=='(') && (number.charAt(4)==')') && (number.charAt(8)=='-') && (d1==true) && (d2==true) && (d3==true) && (d5==true) && (d6==true) && (d7==true) && (d9==true) && (d10==true) && (d11==true) && (d12==true)){
        System.out.println(number + " Is a valid phone number!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(number + " Is not a valid phone number!");
    }
    sc.close();
 } 
}
```

This is also my first post so sorry if it is messy.

Comment: You're trying to check the digits on an empty string.

Comment: I'd use [libphonenumber](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber) instead of re-inventing the wheel (once again): "Google's common Java, C++ and JavaScript library for parsing, formatting, and validating international phone numbers."

Comment: read user input before getting the digits

Answer (score 4):

In this code:

```
String number = "";
boolean d1 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(1));
```

You are initializing `number` as an empty string, and in the next line trying to get the second character of the string (remember - indexes in Java start at `0` and not at `1`).

Probably the easiest fix for you is going to be to move these two lines:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a phone number (ddd)ddd-dddd :");
number = sc.nextLine();
```

To just after the `String number = "";` line, like this:

```
String number = "";
System.out.println("Please enter a phone number (ddd)ddd-dddd :");
number = sc.nextLine();

boolean d1 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(1));
...
```

Note that this will still fail if you don't enter a long enough phone number when prompted. You should probably be validating that your string is long enough before trying to call `String.charAt()` at all.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're checking `number` before it has been instantiated with the value from the `Scanner`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String number;

    System.out.println("Please enter a phone number (ddd)ddd-dddd :");
    number = sc.nextLine();

    boolean d1 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(1));
    boolean d2 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(2));
    boolean d3 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(3));

    boolean d5 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(5));
    boolean d6 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(6));
    boolean d7 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(7));

    boolean d9 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(9));
    boolean d10 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(10));
    boolean d11 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(11));
    boolean d12 = Character.isDigit(number.charAt(12));


    if ((number.length() == 13) && (number.charAt(0)=='(') && (number.charAt(4)==')') && (number.charAt(8)=='-') && (d1==true) && (d2==true) && (d3==true) && (d5==true) && (d6==true) && (d7==true) && (d9==true) && (d10==true) && (d11==true) && (d12==true)){
        System.out.println(number + " Is a valid phone number!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(number + " Is not a valid phone number!");
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

There are far better ways though to check for a phone number however, to fix your issue, we set the initial value of the `number` variable to the value input by the user. Then we are able to perform the `Boolean` checks afterwards the `number` has been initialised correctly.

Your issue before was that you were trying to perform `number.chatAt(1)` and so on when there was no value at 1 because the value was `""`